# Draw a route in Flutter with google_maps_flutter package

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I have a map already drawn with `google_maps_flutter` and I have 2 markers on it. I would like to draw a route between them. Can anybody help me?

When I use the one suggested by [@CopsOnRoad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6618622/copsonroad), I have the picture displayed. I would like the route to be the blue line, which goes the best way forward.

[image: Figure that demonstrates the problem]

Answer (score 5):

Since you haven't shared any code, I am going to give you an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56383841/6618622)

Add this to your `StatefulWidget` subclass.

```
Map<PolylineId, Polyline> _mapPolylines = {};
int _polylineIdCounter = 1;

void _add() {
  final String polylineIdVal = 'polyline_id_$_polylineIdCounter';
  _polylineIdCounter++;
  final PolylineId polylineId = PolylineId(polylineIdVal);

  final Polyline polyline = Polyline(
    polylineId: polylineId,
    consumeTapEvents: true,
    color: Colors.red,
    width: 5,
    points: _createPoints(),
  );

  setState(() {
    _mapPolylines[polylineId] = polyline;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Maps"),
      actions: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _add)],
    ),
    body: GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0, 0), zoom: 4.0),
      polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_mapPolylines.values),
    ),
  );
}

List<LatLng> _createPoints() {
  final List<LatLng> points = <LatLng>[];
  points.add(LatLng(1.875249, 0.845140));
  points.add(LatLng(4.851221, 1.715736));
  points.add(LatLng(8.196142, 2.094979));
  points.add(LatLng(12.196142, 3.094979));
  points.add(LatLng(16.196142, 4.094979));
  points.add(LatLng(20.196142, 5.094979));
  return points;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not submitting code is that the question is generic and not based on existing code.

I had found this code that I am routing, but it draws straight lines from one point to another and not a route based on existing routes from one marker to another.

Am I correct in this?

Comment: Don't you mean line between 2 points a `route`? You must be showing marker on some `LatLng`, using same `LatLng` you can create line or route.

Comment: I inserted a picture in the post that presents what I have with your suggestion and what I would like to have.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but sorry there is no way of doing it as of now that will help you join 2 points via valid road, all you need to do is create many `LatLng` (road latitude and longitude) to print what you desire.

Comment: Ok. Is there no way to get a route with the flutter, or with the plugin? Do you know if there is a plugin that generates this?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way of doing it using any package/plugin, you need `LatLng` every second.

Comment: There is a way to do this. Just see https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmnT6naTGy2TNKTW2W-twfG_gFuCtnFQF. Its great

Comment: That's just link to the playlist, can you share the exact video which does that? Right now I am bit busy on other project so can't watch all the videos.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. The firts video is there in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAIDZxwnEdI&list=PLmnT6naTGy2TNKTW2W-twfG_gFuCtnFQF&index=6&t=0s. There is one more in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uir-x_w-O7U&list=PLmnT6naTGy2TNKTW2W-twfG_gFuCtnFQF&index=6. It' work

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, bit busy in working on some project and had a view from above and couldn't find where exactly the presenter did that, since you have watched the full video, can you share the pin point link for the video?

Answer (score 0):

Good to have a route as you want it is necessary to have several points and valid streets, this in your case is very important. I suggest you pay for an existing service like google direction. You can get the coordinates and street names with google direction.

API (Google Direction)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=LAT,LON&destination=LAT,LON&key=API_KEY
```

Example Draw a route (google direction)

https://github.com/DeveloperLibs/flutter_google_map_route/blob/master/lib/map_screen.dart